# Objects with location, anyone figured it out?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This statment is found in the graph api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

> Objects with location. The following will return information about
>   objects that have location information attached. In addition, the
>   returned objects will be those in which you or your friend have been
>   tagged, or those objects that were created by you or your friends.

But it is not stated how to make this call, has anyone figured it out?

In order to get pure checkins the following is used: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin

Answer (score 0):

> But it is not stated how to make this call, has anyone figured it out?

Like any other Graph API call …? With a simple HTTP request, probably including an access token, or with the help of one of the SDKs, which take care of the more basic aspects of this for you.

Comment: The thing is that this works: [link]https://graph.facebook.com/me/locations?access_token=[/link] but that returns your own location post. If you want to get friends location posts there is no statment of how to do this and [link]https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=locations&access_token=[/link] returns message": "Unsupported type, locations",

Comment: That _may_ be because it’s __location__, not _locations_ …

Comment: changing to location is not the solution, it returns: { "error": { "message": "(#100) Must specify a search location", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100 } } it should not return for a specific location it should return location posts

Comment: Maybe you’ll have more luck with FQL, querying the location_post table …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/

Comment: yes fql works but it can't tell if the user is tagged in the post it will only display those that my friends are author of

Answer (score 0):

If you do a search for location objects you need to include the point and radius for your search, see example below for a search over the center of Gothenburg with 1000 meter distance (max for distance is 50000 meters)

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=57.708549,11.975098&distance=1000&access_token=xxx